# Is there any way to specify game mode (i.e. All Random) using the console?

Tags: dota-2

Is there any way to specify game mode (i.e. All Random) using the console?

I don't see anything about this on [here](http://www.dota2wiki.com/wiki/Console_Command_List) (I know, not an official list), but I thought I'd still ask (and someone can answer here if and when the functionality is added).

`dota_match_game_modes` sounded promising, but it appears to be ["to search for in matchmaking"](http://www.gamerconfig.eu/command/dota-2/dota_match_game_modes/). Tried it nonetheless, didn't do anything.

I use the console to play so I can do so offline because I'm not always connected to the internet and DotA seems to be unable to start offline without `-console`.

Commands I use to start the game: (in case anyone wants to test anything)

> sv_cheats 1; sv_lan 1; dota_start_ai_game 1; dota_bot_set_difficulty 2; map dota_winter

Comment: The main problem is me getting somewhat tired of playing against / with the same characters over and over again (because the bots generally pick very similar characters). Also feel free to suggest a (preferably simple) solution for that.

Comment: The bots only know how to play a selected portion of the cast. There's not much you can do about that.

Comment: So I suppose I'll just have to wait until bots can play all characters and All Random is extended to work for them. Hopefully the console command won't be far behind.

Comment: You can create a custom lobby and just fill it with bots. You can pick the mode, but they do dumb things when they get heroes they don't know how to use.

Comment: Tried that - they don't seem to spawn at all in All Random mode.

Comment: @NotThatGuy Bots currently only work in AP mode.

Answer (score 2):

Play different modes by typing "dota_force_gamemode 1"
IMPORTANT! Type this before you type "map dota"

1. All Pick
2. Captain's Mode
3. Random Draft
4. Single Draft
5. All Random
6. Heroes for Beginners
7. Diretide
8. Reverse Captain's Mode
9. The Greeviling
10. Tutorial
11. Mid Only
12. Least Played
13. New Player Pool (same as 6 except with 1 minute picking time and non-playable heroes grayedout instead of not visible)Everything else after 13 shows up as #game_mode_xx, and is just all pick.